# jquery attribute. jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".dum").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("ev").value=$(this).attr("data-name");
   
    $("#test-form").dialog("open");
});
```

```html
// this is just the test
 
 
cell2.innerHTML = '<span  class="dum" style="color:'+testvalues[i]+'; font-size:20px;">'+testvalues[i + 2] || ''+'data-name=" '+testvalues[i+2] +'">'+ '</span>';


<div id="test-form" title="Event Information">
 <p>Event:</p> 
 <input id= "ev" type="text"  name="fullname" disabled />
</div>
```

I have a `<span>` where I have values from db. And I am trying to get those value to a input box using jquery attr but I am getting undefined. The attr name is "data-name". I do not know what I am doing wrong here. I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: the span tag you are appending doesn't have a class called test

Comment: You have an extra **`>`**

Comment: charlietfl, where is the extra >. please help me locate

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(testvalues)`?

Comment: Below your `input` tag, but that has nothing to do with your problem. Can you explain what you're trying to do here? `'<span  class="dum" style="color:'+testvalues[i]+'; font-size:20px;">'+testvalues[i + 2] || ''+'data-name=" '+testvalues[i+2] +'">'+ '</span>';` What does `testvalues` look like? Can you inspect the spans you are inserting? Is there actually an attribute on the DOM? My impression is that you're never actually writing the attr.

Comment: testvalues[i] outputs the date to table and testvalues[I+1] prints the name. and when clicked on particular table element shows the name in inputbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st**: you need to rewrite the `span`

**2nd**: you need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

**This is an example**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var testvalues = ['red','no','Click Me','name'],
      i = 1;
  $('#cell2').html('<span  class="dum" style="color:'+testvalues[i]+'; font-size:20px;" data-name="'+testvalues[i+2] +'">'+testvalues[i+1] +'</span>');

  $(document).on('click' , ".dum" , function() {
    $("#ev").val($(this).data("name")); 
    //$( "#test-form").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="cell2"></div>

<div id="test-form" title="Event Information">
  <p >Event:</p> 
  <input id= "ev" type="text"  name="fullname" disabled />
</div>
```

> Note: I don't prefer mixing jquery with pure js so I used jquery

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef you are two awesomeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee! thx for great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `span`s you are inserting. I don't think the problem is related to jQuery, rather that you are not actually writing the `data-name` attribute. What is the `||` on the `innerHTML` for? Because of that `||` you are only writing the first part of the string (everything to its left) and nothing to its right (the `data-name` attribute).

Comment: danie I removed ||  tag and it worked perfect.however its writing "data-name" to the table. I was trying to show attr values only when user clicks on the table element with class("dum")

Answer (score -1):

Use the jQuery data attribute instead.

```
 document.getElementById("ev").value=$(this).data("name");
```

Comment: no reason this would work if `attr('data-name')` doesn't work

Comment: attr('data-name'), I am getting undefined.

Comment: I tested this using your code, and I am getting a successful data retrieval. I think your issue is not in the code that you have presented. Perhaps the bug is getting introduced elsewhere?